# Using spread correctly in R: Error

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe inputData with columns acc_id, attrName, attrValue and timeStamp. The acc_id column will have duplicate entries because an example head of the data will be like this:

```
acc_id, attr_name, attr_value, timeStamp
123      abcVar1    138         Nov 1 2017
123      abcVar2    10          Nov 1 2017
123      abcVar3    2124        Nov 1 2017
468      abcVar1    13         Nov 9 2017
468      abcVar2    13458         Nov 9 2017
468      abcVar3    1238         Nov 9 2017
```

The situation can be generalized where attr_name will have a lot more than just 3 unique variables as well.

It needs to be converted into the format

```
acc_id abcVar1 abcVar2 abcVar3 timeStamp
123     138      10      2124  Nov 1 2017
468     13       13458   1238  Nov 9 2017
```

I tried spread(inputData,attr_name, attr_val) to get error

Comment: It works for me. Double check the column names of your dataframe. Those commas there look very suspicious. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Error looks like this: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (9133, 298508), (12964, 362873), (30292, 422239), (45219, 382008), (59141, 191802), (94219, 324737), (116840, 168859),... I gave example data in the question in the format I have.

Comment: Can't replicate your issue. Also, your column name is `attr_value`, but you're using `attr_val` inside `spread`. Are you sure it's the same, or similar dataset?

Comment: If my answer below works for you, then you have to post a more representative dataset. Maybe include the rows that create the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example above I get this:

```
library(tidyr)

df = read.table(text = "
acc_id attr_name attr_value timeStamp
123      abcVar1    138         Nov_1_2017
123      abcVar2    10          Nov_1_2017
123      abcVar3    2124        Nov_1_2017
468      abcVar1    13          Nov_9_2017
468      abcVar2    13458       Nov_9_2017
468      abcVar3    1238        Nov_9_2017
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

spread(df, attr_name, attr_value)

#   acc_id  timeStamp abcVar1 abcVar2 abcVar3
# 1    123 Nov_1_2017     138      10    2124
# 2    468 Nov_9_2017      13   13458    1238
```

Maybe your example dataframe is not representative of your actual dataset.
I cannot replicate your problem.

However, it seems to break when there are duplicate rows like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df = read.table(text = "
acc_id attr_name attr_value timeStamp
123      abcVar1    138         Nov_1_2017
123      abcVar2    10          Nov_1_2017
123      abcVar3    2124        Nov_1_2017
468      abcVar1    13          Nov_9_2017
468      abcVar1    13          Nov_9_2017
468      abcVar2    13458       Nov_9_2017
468      abcVar3    1238        Nov_9_2017
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

spread(df, attr_name, attr_value)

# Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (4, 5)

# deduplicate and reshape
df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  spread(attr_name, attr_value)

#   acc_id  timeStamp abcVar1 abcVar2 abcVar3
# 1    123 Nov_1_2017     138      10    2124
# 2    468 Nov_9_2017      13   13458    1238
```

Comment: I checked. The example is representative if the dataset. It does run for some subsets of rows in my example while for some subsets I get the error:      Traceback:
  
    1. spread(as.data.frame(cosmosDiva), attr_name, attr_value)
2. spread.data.frame(as.data.frame(cosmosDiva), attr_name, attr_value)
3. abort(glue("Duplicate identifiers for rows {rows}"))

Comment: Can you check if you have duplicate rows in your dataframe? Check my updated answer above.

Comment: That is precisely the issue! I checked, the pairs of rows it returns in (,) in the error. They are duplicates! Is there a way for deduping it as part of the spread or do we need to dedup it seprately using something like duplicated? What is an efficient way to do it either way.

Comment: Yes, you can use `dplyr`'s `distinct` command before. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm